# Selenium Chrome webdriver can't find elements after content is reloaded

Tags: selenium

I'm testing a page where the div reloads with a form that has multiple textboxesand buttons.  However after the div is reloaded the webdriver can't find any of the elements on the screen.  I've tried different waits but it never finds the elements.  However, when I try to find an element that didn't change (i.e. a top nav element) it finds it fine.

```
        Driver.Instance.FindElement(By.Id("igtxttxt_CAge")).Click();
        var wait = new WebDriverWait(Driver.Instance, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
        wait.Until(d => d.SwitchTo().ActiveElement().GetAttribute("id") == "igtxttxt_CAge");
```

Is there something I can do for when the div content is refreshed?

**Error received:**

> no such element: Unable to locate element:
>   {"method":"id","selector":"igtxttxt_CAge"}
>
> (Session info: chrome=56.0.2924.76)
>
> (Driver info: chromedriver=2.27.440174

Comment: Not sure if it's your issue, but make sure to always switch back to the top frame before searching for an element or switching to a new frame.

    driver.switchTo().defaultContent();

Comment: @HedonicHedgehog - I tried that.  Same result.  But good to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer to this question.  I didn't realize until I looked at the HTML content that the Driver contained that the page I was loading was loaded in an `iFrame`.

Once I added this code:

```
 Driver.Instance.SwitchTo().Frame("frame_Calculator");
```

Then the rest of my code worked as expected:

```
        Driver.Instance.FindElement(By.Id("igtxttxt_CAge")).Click();
        ((IJavaScriptExecutor)Driver.Instance).ExecuteScript("$('#igtxttxt_CAge').trigger('focus')");
```

Answer (score 0):

In your given scenario, I think `fluentwait` is better candidate than `webdriverwait`. You can try the following code. It will ignore all such no `element not found exception`s while the `webdriver` waits.

```
FluentWait fluentWait = new FluentWait<>(webDriver) {
  .withTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
  .pollingEvery(200, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
  .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class, TimeoutException.class)
  .ignoring(StaleElementReferenceException.class);
}
```

And the you can use it until your element is clickable or visible.

```
fluentWait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(By.Id("igtxttxt_CAge")));
fluentWait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.Id("igtxttxt_CAge")));
```

Hope this will help. here is a [difference](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/12866/how-fluentwait-is-different-from-webdriverwait) between webdriverwait and fluentwait.